# CDLaTeX: No such modifier ‘t’ outside math mode

Tags: latex, auctex

I'm trying out CDLaTeX, but I'm running into the problem that when typing e.g. "don't" in text mode, I get:

`cdlatex-math-modify: No such modifier ‘t’ outside math mode`

I have a similar problem with "I'm". These modifiers work fine in math mode, and typing e.g. "it's" is fine too.

If I show the list of available modifiers by '?, t and m are both there, with blanks next to them, which I presume should mean (as the documentation suggests) that 't should just produce 't - or should it actually be showing something nonempty?